# Recreating Arraylist class

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on recreating the ArrayList class. I have a problem with the `add` method. I want my `add` method to return the new table and to affect it to my element. But when I want to get into the element of my table element it's always `null`. 
And another question..I wanna Create the constructor that takes objects as the elements of the Arraylist like `ArrayListBis(1,2,3)`..what's gonna be the parameter of the contractor is it `ArrayListBis(Object... args)` ?

```
public class ArrayListBis  {

final static int DEFAULTSIZE=50;
private int indexCourant,dernierElement,size;
private Object [] elements;

public ArrayListBis(int size){
    elements=creatList(size);
    indexCourant=0;
    dernierElement=size-1;
    this.size=size;
}

public void add(Object o){
    add(o,size());
}

public void add(Object o, int index){
    Object[] temp;
    if(index <0 || index > size())
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    else{
            temp=creatList(size()+1);
            for(int i=0;i!=size()+1;i++){
                if(i<index)
                    temp[i]=elements[i];
                else if(i==index)
                    temp[i]=elements[index];
                else
                    temp[i]=elements[i+1];
            }
        this.size++;
            elements=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your `size` method?

Comment: i didn't past all the code : this is my methode size() : public int size(){
        return size;
    }

Comment: @AbdoRabah Post all relevant code in the question.

Comment: You never assign `o` to an element of the array, do you?

Comment: Read your method. It takes an Object o to add to the list, but you're never using that argument anywhere in the method.

Comment: Suggestion: don't call variables `o`. It's too much like an `0`, and doesn't convey what it is. `obj` is a clearer but concise alternative.

Comment: also why are you creating a new list everytime you add something to your list?

Comment: Nothing to do with the actual problem, but you might want to use generics as well if you recreate it.

Comment: @AndyTurner lol omg i see that i have forgotten the important code line of that object i wanna add .. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisGong Yeah you are right i'll change that it's a stupid beginner solution..but i used it to copy the elements of the "element" table because it's going to be changed

Comment: @JB Nizet  i have forgotten the important code line of that object i wanna add .. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple issues with your add method. First, you do not need to recreate your list every time a new element is added. The reason is that your list will not start out full, hence this line

```
add(o,size());
```

should only be done on the condition that `this.size == elements.length`. However, I believe you should use `size` or some variable to reflect the actual count of how many elements were inserted so far into your arraylist. So in your constructor, I would set `this.size = 0` instead since it starts out with zero elements. Now in your original `add` method, only create a new array if you're adding to an array that's full. And like others have said, you weren't adding the new element to begin with. So with those changes it should now look like this,

```
public void add(Object o, int index){
    Object[] temp;
    if(index >= 0 && index < elements.length)
        temp[index] = o;
        size++;
    else{
        temp=creatList(elements.length * 2);
        for(int i=0;i < elements.length;i++){
            if(i<index)
                temp[i]=elements[i];
            else if(i==index)
                temp[i]=o;
            else
                temp[i]=elements[i+1];
        }
        temp[index] = 0;
        size++;
        this.elements = temp;
    }
}
```

Only other thing I changed was how much the new list's size should be. I changed it to be double the original array's size because you don't want to make a new array of a size that's only one more bigger than the original because making new arrays and copying all the elements from the old one to the new one is a costly operation that shouldn't be done too often.

Comment: Thanks for you help ! the `size` variable that you asked me to add is a good idea..and about the line `add(o,size())` in the method `add(o)` it's for adding the object at the end of the array

Comment: @AbdoRabah No problem. If you found the answer then dont forget to accept or upvote it. Good luck coding!

Comment: Can you please tell me why this line `temp[index] = 0;`

Comment: @AbdoRabah I apologize that this is a bit late, but the reason I do that is because my method above is only for adding to the end of the list. If you want to add to the middle of a list, then the method's implementation would have to be different. Hope you ended up getting this, but I'd still be happy to give you an answer to adding to the middle of the array. Cheers